# pion-network library installation

Tags: c++, windows, embedded, pion-net

I have downloaded and installed the pion network library.

I am trying to build the sample web services (HelloService etc). However, I cannot find instructions on how to build the examples. 
I am developing on windows7

Answer (score 0):

Check [This](http://www.pion.org/files/pion-net/common/doc/README.msvc) for build instructions on Windows.
You might also want to see [here](http://www.pion.org/projects/pion-network-library/download) the compatibility of your windows.

Comment: yes, i used that, but still i got some errors like error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall pion::net::HTTPWriter::send(void)"